# Saving a three-dimensional matrix as multiple two-dimensional .mat files

Tags: matlab

Suppose I have a three-dimensional matrix called A.

I would like to save `A(1,1:n,:), A(2,1:n,:), A(3,1:n,:)` etc.  as separate two-dimensional .mat files: `squeeze(A(1,1:n,:)`.

I'm guessing there might be an easy way to go about this that I'm not aware of.

Thank you very much!

Comment: .mat files can only save variables. So you need to define those variables and then save them: `A1 = squeeze(A(1,1:n,:)); save file1 A1`, etc

Comment: Is there any way to use a for-loop for this? Somehow `A',num2str(i) = squeeze(A(i,1:n,:))` doesn't quite work.

Comment: `eval(['A', num2str(i), ' = squeeze(A(i,1:n,:));']);` will do. The assignment command is synthesized as a string here, and then it is evaluated by `eval`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See my comment to define and assign variables programmatically. However, you probably don't need that here. As you suggest, you could loop

```
for i = 1 : 5
    B = squeeze(A(i, 1 : n, :);
    save(['slice', num2str(i), '.mat'], 'B');
end
```

and assign it to one variable that you write to different files.